# Eclipse project gives warnings without saying where

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

I have a problem, my eclipse gives me warnings on my project, but doesn't show where the warning is:

[image: Eclipse project]

I know that all my files are 100% clean, and they are not the cause.

**Question:** How do I know what the warning is in cases like these?

Comment: Try clean building the project once and also check the 'Problems View'

Comment: @ParthSatra I know I can do that, but the question is: How do I know what the warning is? (Because Im sure eclipse would like to tell that ;))

Comment: When I use Eclipse, there's a window at the bottom with several tabs--usually Console is one of the tabs, but Problems is one of the others.  That's how Eclipse was set up for me, by default.  If that window is there for you, that would be the easiest way to find error and warning messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if open the `Problems` view

```
Alt-Shift-Q
```

or

```
File->Show View->Problems
```

you will be able to see them